# OpenXml Power Tools: Split docx into multiple html files by pages

Tags: openxml

In OpenXml Power Tools, can I convert a docx file to html files by pages? (A docx with 2 pages would result in 2 html files)

Comment: Hi have you managed to find solution for your question? i want to do the same thing but can not find anything on it.